# Implement a Thread by providing a new class that extends Thread and overriding its run() method

Tags: android, multithreading, service, background

Implementing a Thread by providing a new class that extends Thread and overriding its run() method is new to me. I've tried all day to get it to work. Here's my code:

```
/*
 * see http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Thread.html
 */
class threadClass extends Thread {
    private Handler mHandler;
    private Message mMsg;
    // constructor
    public threadClass(Handler handler, Message msg) {
        // do something like save the Handler reference
        mHandler = handler;
        mMsg = msg;
    }
    @Override
    public void run() {
        // do some background processing, call the Handler?
        mHandler.sendMessage(mMsg);
    }
}
public Thread passHandlerToThread(Handler handler) {
    handler.sendEmptyMessage(10);
    Message msg = Message.obtain();
    msg.what = 10;
    Thread thread = new threadClass(handler, msg);
    return thread;
}
private Handler localHandler = new Handler() {
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        int what = msg.what;
        if (what == 10) Log.i("localHandler", "what: " + what);
    }
};
public void startThread() {
    Thread thread = passHandlerToThread(localHandler);
    thread.start();
}
```

I call startThread() in my LocalService onCreate() but nothing happens. What am I doing wrong? I was expecting localHandler() to be called twice: once in passHandlerToThread() and again in run().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do something like this:

```
private final Handler handler = new Handler();
// toast runnables
final Runnable updateTwitterNotification = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        dismissProgressSpinner();
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Tweet sent!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
};  

final Runnable updateCreateError = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Tweet error!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
};

postMessageInThread();


//implementation:
private void postMessageInThread() {
    Thread t = new Thread() {
        @Override
        public void run() {

            try {
                connectToTwitterService() // or whatever
                handler.post(updateTwitterNotification);
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Error sending msg", ex);
                handler.post(updateCreateError);
            }
        }
    };
    t.start();
}
```

Comment: your answer to me does not resemble the two described in [Thread](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Thread.html). But hey it's nice to have a third approach. So I accept your answer and will vote it up. Can I ask if you like my question please vote it up?

Comment: I Like your question - so yes, I'll vote it up. :). Funny, this is the way I handle most of my threads - maybe I'll go take a look at the documentation...

Comment: Oops, just checked the docs - I see why you were confused - I missed out the @Override flag - I've added it now.